# What kind of microphone and audio interface needed for indoor TDOA sourcing

Tags: microphone

I am working on a project and experimenting with trilaterating the location of a loud sound source, using 3 microphones placed around a room. I currently use cheap M1 Movo USB microphones, but the lack of clock synchronization of USB microphones is a big problem. I am planning on getting some better XLR based microphone equipment. Any recommendations for microphone and sound interface? The microphone needs to be small preferably, like a lavalier mic size. What kind of characteristics in microphone do I need to look out for my application? What kind of pickup pattern, transducer, sensitivity, signal to noise ratio.etc is important?

Comment: "lack of clock synchronization of USB microphones" - I'm assuming you're on Windows? You can clock sync USB mics/interfaces on Mac in Audio/Midi Setup.